# MYSQL: Select entries in relation to multiple rows of another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in a database:

- entries (ID, distance, status[,...])
- entriesmeta (ID, entry_ID, metakey, metavalue)

Until now, I select entries like this:

```
SELECT ID,
distance
FROM entries
WHERE status = '2' HAVING distance < 30
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 20
```

Now, the second table contains data of this sort:

```
ID | entry_ID | metakey | metavalue
1  | 137      | service | 13
2  | 137      | service | 7
3  | 137      | service | 76
4  | 84       | service | 23
etc.
```

The entries in the first table are restaurants, the services in the second table are services they offer. What I have been trying for a while now is this: Create a HTML search form that lets users choose certain services via checkboxes. The MYSQL query then should select all entries that offer ALL those services. So far, the search form puts the selected services in an array (7,13,9,27).

My problem is finding the correct database query. It should match the metavalue-field with the checkbox-array and then select all entries from the first table, which offer all those services. I have been experimenting with "LEFT JOIN ON entries.ID = entriesmeta.entry_ID" and several WHERE clauses, but no success. I wonder if someone can help.

Thank you in advance - and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: can you post the query statement that you have as of now ?

Comment: you may want to use this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aef18/2 (note SQLFiddle Demo is based off the anwser from user 491243)  to optimize when you expect an high number of records in both tables and remove the need off "Using temporary, using filesort" what are really performance killers for MySQL because the sorting could be done on disk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  e.ID
FROM    entries e
        INNER JOIN entriesmeta m
            ON e.ID = m.entry_id
WHERE   
        m.metakey = 'service' AND
        m.metavalue IN (7,13,9,27)
GROUP   BY e.ID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT m.metavalue) = 4
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2869/1)

This query will display all `ID` that has `metakey` of `service` and a value(*s*) of `7, 13, 9, 27`.

Comment: @AlexP if there are possiblities that `metavalue` is not unique. anyway, if it's unique, you can simply remove `DISTINCT` and change it to `HAVING  COUNT(*) = 4` http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2869/2

Comment: I did not need `DISTINCT`, since `metavalue`is unique. Otherwise it is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This would get you all `entries` which have a given `entriesmeta` service value - which is what I think you are asking.

```
 SELECT entries.* from entriesmeta
 INNER JOIN entries on entries.ID = entriesmeta.entry_ID
 WHERE entriesmeta.metavalue = <myValue>
```